# Powershell Help: How can I remove duplicates (using multiple columns simultaneously, not sequentially)?

Tags: powershell, csv, duplicates

I have tried several different variations based on some other stack overflow articles, but I will share a sample of what I have and a sample output and then some cobbled-together code hoping for some direction from the community:

*C:\Scripts\contacts.csv*:

```
id,first_name,last_name,email
1,john,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
1,jane,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
2,jane,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
2,john,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
3,sam,jones,sjones@notreal.com
3,sandy,jones,sandy@notreal.com
```

Need to turn this into a file where column "email" is unique to column "id". In other words there can be duplicate addresses, but only if there is a different id.

desired output *C:\Scripts\contacts-trimmed.csv*:

```
id,first_name,last_name,email
1,john,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
2,john,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
3,sam,jones,sjones@notreal.com
3,sandy,jones,sandy@notreal.com
```

I have tried this with a few different variations:

```
Import-Csv C:\Scripts\contacts.csv | sort first_name | Sort-Object -Property id,email -Unique | Export-Csv C:\Scripts\contacts-trim.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help or direction would be most appreciated

Comment: What are the rules for discarding duplicates? I. e. why isn't the 2nd row of desired output `2,jane,smith,jsmith@notreal.com`?

Comment: the email address is the same even though the name is different.  Basically, there can be multiple id's and multiple emails, but no duplicates of email for each id.  So the group of id and email must be unique.

Comment: When going through the records one by one, I understand that you keep first record and discard second, because same ID and same email. Taking 3rd record, there is a new ID, so shouldn't 3rd record be kept and 4th one discarded?

Comment: Without getting too in depth... There can only be one user with an email address and the id is a student id.  Many of our parents have multiple students and we can only have one parent with an email, but in many situations the parents both use the same email.  We have to eliminate one or the other, but can't keep both so I  have to sort by first name so that when it eliminates duplicates; it completely eliminates one of the parents and keeps the other if they are assigned to multiple students.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`Group-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object), to, well, *group together records with similar values*:

```
$records = @'
id,first_name,last_name,email
1,john,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
1,jane,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
2,jane,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
2,john,smith,jsmith@notreal.com
3,sam,jones,sjones@notreal.com
3,sandy,jones,sandy@notreal.com
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv

# group records based on id and email column
$records |Group-Object id,email |ForEach-Object {
  # grab only the first record from each group
  $_.Group |Select-Object -First 1
} |Export-Csv .\no_duplicates.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Btw, this produces the same output as `$records | Sort-Object id, email -Unique`. It doesn't match OPs "desired" output though...

Comment: unless I am missing something the above answer seemed to work.  I am checking through the output now.

Comment: It produces `2,jane...` as the 2nd line, while in OPs "desired" output it is `2,john...`. I think your output is correct though and OPs "desired" output isn't (unless I'm missing something ;-)).

Comment: @Andy if you need to explicitly sort the individual groups, you can always change the inner pipeline to `$_.Group |Sort-Object Name -Descending |Select-Object -First1` for example

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you for your help.  your code pointed me in the right direction.  I'm new to powershell and was stumped :)

Comment: @zett42 you are correct above about john not  jane.  I just sorted before adding parts of the code above and it works as I needed.  I am thrilled it works and am most appreciative to both of you for the help :)

Comment: @Andy That's great, good luck on your PowerShell journey! :-)